# Loading Plaid JS from CDN in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plaid

I'm trying to get Plaid working in VueJS but I just can't get the JS loading.

This works fine using Vanilla JS:
https://jsfiddle.net/5vnh2ubs/

But this just doesn't seem to work:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{ pl }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  beforeMount() {
    this.pl = this.Plaid;
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pl: null,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I've tried importing the script in the index.html file and used vue-plugin-load-script but nothing seems to work.

I've never had this issue when loading JS files in the index.html file.

**Edit:**

This is how I've tried loading it using vue-plugin-load-script:

```js
this.$loadScript('https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js')
.then(() => {
    console.log(this.Plaid);
})
.catch(() => {
    console.log('error');
});
```

And in index.html, it's a simple script tag between the head tags:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
```

I can see the script tag is there when I inspect elements but calling Plaid returns nothing.

Comment: Can you provide the code for how you've imported the script in `index.html` and the configuration of `vue-plugin-load-script`.

Worth mentioning this module exists: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-plaid-link

Comment: Hi Nick, have amended my original post. I've tried using that package but it's causing issues of it's own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Plaid CDN script creates a global variable: `window.Plaid`. However, your component incorrectly refers to it via `this.Plaid`. In the Vue SFC, `this` is the component instance, which only contains its own properties declared in the component definition. `this` does not include global variables from `window`.

The solution is to use `window.Plaid`:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pl: window.Plaid,
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-plaid-link?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FPlaidLink.vue)

Comment: Thanks Tony. Such an amateur mistake. I've done this before so should have known.

Comment: @sn1234 The demo link shows the version of Plaid loaded from `window.Plaid`. It's not intended to "open a Plaid window". You're looking for a different solution. I recommend posting a new question so that someone familiar with the topic can answer. I'll chime in if I can.

Comment: @tony19 Sure i have added new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74333426/integrate-plaid-with-quasar-version2-vuejs-version3-to-open-the-plaid-window)